# Android Unable to generate multiple notifications from my app

Tags: android, android-notifications

After reading multiple posts I have tried everything to generate a new notification for every alert using unique id. However this is not working. Following is my code:-

> ```
>                  //Generate random id for notification
>                  Random r=new Random();
>                  int id=r.nextInt(9999);
>
>                  PendingIntent intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), id, notificationIntent, 0);
>
>                   Builder notice2=new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
>                      .setContentTitle(call.getName())
>                      .setAutoCancel(true)
>                      .setContentIntent(intent)
>                      .setContentText("Context")
>                      .setSmallIcon(com.project.calltracker.R.drawable.ic_alert)
>                      .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), com.project.calltracker.R.drawable.ic_logo));
>                      startForeground(id, notice2.getNotification());
> ```

As you can see I am using a random integer as Id each time I generate a notification. But still I only get a single notification no matter how many times I startForeground is called??

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: did you check `id` number that is unique or not?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan yes I checked....its unique every time

Comment: see my answer on follow link to send multiple notification, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108421/multiple-notifications-for-one-activity/21108440#21108440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there's always just ONE foreground service running. Services are singletons by nature, there can't be 2 instances of the same service running.

If you want to just send multiple notifications you should use the [notification manager, notify() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)

Comment: Thank you @Budius!! Your explanation really cleared my concept here!

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to generate a random `id`, using a sequence of `id`s will be more safe and ensure that all the `id`s are unique

```
PendingIntent intent = null;
Builder notice2=null;
int N = 1000; //set this value
for(int id=1;id<N; id++){

             intent =PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), id, notificationIntent, 0);

              notice2=new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                 .setContentTitle(call.getName())
                 .setAutoCancel(true)
                 .setContentIntent(intent)
                 .setContentText("Context")
                 .setSmallIcon(com.project.calltracker.R.drawable.ic_alert)
                 .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), com.project.calltracker.R.drawable.ic_logo));

             startForeground(id, notice2.getNotification());
}
```

I hope it helps