# How to set multiple notification using a unique ID?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I trying to put notification for my todo list. The notification works, but for only 1 item, how do I set for multiple notifications. If I put two items for notification, only the last one that I set will show up a notification. Here is my code for the alarm task.

```
public class AlarmTask implements Runnable{
// The date selected for the alarm
private final Calendar date;


// The android system alarm manager
private final AlarmManager am;
// Your context to retrieve the alarm manager from
private final Context context;


public AlarmTask(Context context, Calendar date) {
    this.context = context;
    this.am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    this.date = date;



}



@Override
public void run() {
    // Request to start  service when the alarm date is upon us
    // We don't start an activity as we just want to pop up a notification into the system bar not a full activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);


    // Sets an alarm - note this alarm will be lost if the phone is turned off and on again
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, date.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

}

Comment: you can either use a badge to set the number of notification, as well as two notifications with different id.

Comment: You need different notifications ID in order to have different notifications

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108421/multiple-notifications-for-one-activity/21108440#21108440